# Print content of <P> html, perl

Tags: html, perl

i'm doing perl programming. i'm opening a input of .html. i want to copy the content of `<P>` tag into variables so that i can used the content only and make some changes to the content

below is my code

```
use utf8;
package MyParser;
use base qw(HTML::Parser);

$lines = <INPUT>;
my $parser = MyParser->new;
$parser->parse( $lines );
print $lines;
```

but it print only (!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ......) 
does anyone know how to it?

thanks in advance

Comment: Whitespace? In my match operator (`=~`)?

Comment: You say "*but it print only (!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ......)*". Well, that's because you read a single line from `INPUT`: `$lines = <INPUT>;` `$lines` is a **scalar**.

Comment: got it, but how i want to take only in the <P> and assign it to new variables?

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple) for simple stream parsing of HTML documents.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(...);

while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('p')) {
    print $parser->get_trimmed_text('/p'), "\n";
}
```

If you want the entire document tree to query and change, [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder) will give you an [HTML::Tree](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTree).

Comment: why it gave me can't call method get_tag on an undefined value

Comment: i used this $lines = <INPUT>;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(\$lines);

while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('P')) {
    print $parser->get_trimmed_text('/P'), "\n";
} but nothing in the output

Comment: i got it now HTML::TokeParser=HASH(0x2536560)HTML::TokeParser=HASH(0x2536638).. while ($lines = <INPUT>)
{
  my $parser = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$lines);

  while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('p')) {
      $parser->get_trimmed_text('/p'), "\n";
      print $parser;
  }
}

Comment: i'm sorry, i can't get it.. :(

Comment: i get already if print using tag, but if i print using tag, there's a lot will print, i'm trying to change reading based on tag and class.. i'm a beginner, just start writing perl..

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the use of a parser ([HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aParser)), and avoid the use of regular expressions to do this kind os tasks

Comment: can you show me how.. i'm a beginner in perl.. still searching

Comment: yes, you can find a simple HTML::Parser example here: http://perlmeme.org/tutorials

Comment: i'm doing like this..use utf8;
use HTML::Parser;

$lines = <INPUT>;
$parser = new MyParser;
$parser->parse($content);

{
    package MyParser;
    use base qw(HTML::Parser);

    # this method supplies the text, no tags :)
    sub text {
        my ($self, $origtext) = @_;
        print $origtext, "\n";
    }
}